# Load ruby on rails template from database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, templates, actionview

I wonder if there is a way for me to store ruby on rails view files into database store and have that fetched directly from there. The reason is I want to create a CMS with all the user data stored in database, so I would like to have the template stored in database but still retain the whole ActionView mechanism.

Comment: Could you not do both? Store all the user data in the database, and have a template file with areas defined for the user data?

Comment: That's not the same- I need both the template and data available for user modifications.

Comment: just an idea, you could write the database template to a file in a specified path on demand, then point rails to the created file as a hard template

Answer (score 2):

If there are only a few cases, you can simple use render:

```
template = UserTemplate.find(<find criteria>)
render :inline => template.text
```

(Assuming that `UserTemplate` is the class modeling the templates)

Note, however, that I would primarily use database templates for dynamically modified templates.  There are certainly uses for it -- at [Rhiza](http://www.rhizalabs.com/) we allow for customers to modify their welcome section dynamically, which would require a dynamic template.

Comment: AR! Right that's a good reminder, if there is no better alternatives, your answer make sense.

Comment: @KathyVanStone first I want to thank you about this answer, I now it's a little old back to 2010, but I want to know your opinion about liquid template, is there maybe an advantage to use liquid template instead of "render :inline" method ? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Solution for your problem is the Template Engine in Rails .

[Liquid](http://www.liquidmarkup.org/) template engine is an extraction from the e-commerce system Shopify. Shopify powers many thousands of e-commerce stores which all call for unique designs.

[MasterView](http://masterview.org/) : Alternative Template Engine in Rails .

Choose the one which suits your requirement .

Hope this helps !

Comment: I tried liquid, don't like it. Unless security is the main concern, liquid is a bad thing to put in your hands when you are developing website.
MasterView haven't tried, will take a look, but my question ultimately is the template storage abstraction, not sure if there is a mechanism for that.

Answer (score 1):

Creating a custom template resolver is the way to go. Check [this](http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2011/04/default-views-in-rails-3-0-with-custom-resolvers/). You need a custom resolver that instead of fetching from the filesystem, fetches from the database.